# How to run "updateplatform -p android" Command on android studio shell or terminal

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, terminal

Try to run updateplatform -p android on Android studio terminal but get this error

C:\Users\bpl\AndroidStudioProjects\ShopnRoar\shopnroar-android>sdkmanager --list
'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.